# GMSMapView not showing anything if constraints are added from the Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, nslayoutconstraint, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a UIView inside a UIScrollView. I have given it the custom GMSMapView class. I need this view nestled between two other views.

I am using **Swift 5**, **Xcode 11.3** and **GoogleMaps (3.7.0)**

The map shows up normally if I do not add any constraints to the UIView.

However as soon as I add constraints to the view the map stops displaying anything. The constraints I am adding are `leading` and `trailing` to the UIScrollView and `vertical spacing` to the top and bottom views.

I have tried `mapView.layoutIfNeeded()` in `viewDidLoad()` as suggested in an answer here. But nothing seems to work.

[image]

Comment: Why you have a scrollView ? please show hierarchy in Ib and how you set constraints with screen shoots

Comment: @Sh_Khan added the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

1-Set a height constraint to the mapView

2-Inner top view width = main vc's view width

3-Hook all views properly from top to down inside the scrollView

Comment: I'm almost sure I had already tried that. But it worked this time around.